# java returning "NoClassDefFound" error; thinks -jar option is a runnable class

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror, java-6

```
java -jar <Name of executable jar>
```

Results in my 1.6 jvm returning a `NoClassDefFound` error for 'jar'. Why isn't it recognising `-jar` as an option and not a class to run?

jar structure:
The manifest points Main-Class at com.mycompany.EntryPoint.class, which is inside the jar. It also specifies Ant-Version too and I haven't set ANT_HOME env variable (running on windows).

exact runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ûjar
caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ûjar
...
```

manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.1
Created-By: [redacted]
Main-Class: com/mycompany/EntryPoint
```

Edit: No idea why but I tried it once more and this time it executed the jar as expected.

Comment: It probably does. It does not find the class _inside_ the JAR. Please, post your JAR's structure and the content of your manifest.

Comment: Please see my update. I see no mention of java trying to find the Class mentioned in the manifest. For instance, if I add in some other option instead of -jar it will look for a class named after that option instead, so it's not working with command line flags as expected.

Comment: What is the exact message of the error ?

Comment: NoClassDefFound , does it tell you which class ?

Comment: please see my update, sorry am copying from different box by hand.

Comment: Have you copied and pasted `java -jar <Name of executable jar>` from a document or other source ? Have you tried to type the command yourself ?

Comment: edit: I have no idea why, but I tried it one more time and now it executes...

Comment: Now admit it, you didn't type it yourself the first time !

Comment: I honestly did! All manner of java -version java -classpath and java -jar. I'm not really sure what's going on :S

Comment: I liked this article which discribes a similar situation: http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2008/01/02/debugging-users-and-invisible-characters/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the '-' character you're using for the '-jar' flag is not the standard ASCII '-' sign, but some kind of UTF-8 special character.

Remove it and replace it with the normal ASCII '-' sign.

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from a bad character in the command line. Most surely you are copying and pasteing `java -jar <Name of executable jar>`.

Write it manually ; )

Answer (score 0):

You need to check couple of things:

1. Check whether manifest file is present in your jar META-INF directory
2. If manifest file present, then whether it contains the details about your main class that need to be run when you call java -jar . Manifest file should look like this:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Main-Class: name of class containing main

Make sure you have a  line break after the last line of Manifest.mf.

Comment: @user1561108 Make sure you have a  line break after the last line of Manifest.mf.

Comment: share your manifest, and the details about the file you are trying to run using this jar